# Convert a dictionary to something readable in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

When I print I get:

```
Counter({'pit': 6, 'mike': 4, 'andy': 3, 'jose': 2})
<class 'collections.Counter'>
```

How can I convert the result into:

```
pit = 6
mike = 4
andy = 3
jose = 2
```

Or a text file that shows:

```
 pit    6
 mike   4
 andy   3
 jose   2
```

Comment: This should assist you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294889/iterating-over-dictionaries-for-loops-in-python

Answer (score 5):

```
for k,v in myCounter.iteritems():
  print "%s = %s" %(k, v)
```

Comment: In Python 3.x, simply change `.iteritems()` to `.items()`

Answer (score 1):

If you want you can extend `dict` object and override the [`__str__()`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__) function to something like this :

```
def __str__(self):
    out = ''
    for k, v in self.iteritems():
        out += "%s\t%s" % (k, v)
    return out
```

This should output what you want each time, the object is represented or printed.